# Updating ROS package

Tags: ros, navigation, installation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to update the costmap_2d package in ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225292/updating-ros-package/) by [mayank_m](https://answers.ros.org/users/24140/mayank_m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you mean version update to a new debian package, you can just simply use `apt`, like; `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-costmap-2d` . This will install the package if it is not installed, or upgrade it if it is installed and an upgrade is available. Of course before this operations it will be better to update repositories with `sudo apt-get update`.

For only upgrade (no install if it is not installed), you can use `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install ros-indigo-costmap-2d` .

If you installed it from source, you should update your files according to the version control system used. For example if it is a `git` repository, and you installed it with `git clone`, you can just use `git pull`, or `git fetch` and `merge`.

Hope I got your point.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8